# How to, so to speak, restart or close browser after every protractor -spec test

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am implementing Protractor test for a web app. I have done some google searching but I have come up with zip, I want to every spec that I create to close the browser after it has ran all of the test in that specific spec file and then continue on to the next -spec file, etc. I've things such as using "beforeAll" and "afterAll" but Jasmine doesn't recognize these methods. A point in the right direction would be awesome!

describe('i will put something more meaningful here later :)', function () {

```
//not sure if this method actually exist in Jasmine
afterAll(function () {
   //restart browser or something of the nature
});

it('should do stuff', function () {

});

it('do stuff', function () {

});
```

});

browser should then close, and then open back up to run the next spec.

Comment: Could you provide some code of what you already tried and where you are running into problems?

Comment: I can't gov'ment work lol. I'll add a skimmed down example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Speaking about restarting browser between tests, there is a relevant configuration option:

```
// If true, protractor will restart the browser between each test.
// CAUTION: This will cause your tests to slow down drastically.
restartBrowserBetweenTests: false,
```

Set it to `true`.

FYI, Here is the initial feature request:

- [Feature Request: to have an option to restart new browser session between each test case/scenario](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1435)

---

`beforeAll` and `afterAll` are built into `jasmine-2.x`. To make them work, you need to set [`jasmine2` as a testing framework](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/362) in the [protractor config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/1e60a9504c883a95f3500eafa38e1fc11dc28c9b/docs/referenceConf.js):

```
exports.config = {
    ...
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    ...
}
```

---

For `jasmine-1.x`, there is a third-party [`jasmine-beforeAll`](https://github.com/nonplus/jasmine-beforeAll) package that provides the same exact functionality.

Comment: That worked great! Would you by chance know if it's possible to open and close the browser, before and after each spec file has ran?

Comment: @JosephFreeman great! Please see the update, hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! That does work, but it restarts that browser between each 'it' block lol :) that's not exactly the functionality I'm looking for. Do you know a link to a list of all the possibly protractor config options?

Comment: @JosephFreeman see [referenceConf.js](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js), but I'm not sure there is a specific setting for it..

Comment: restartBrowserBetweenTests: true; not working for me. It restarts the browser and quickly closes before running the next spec.

Comment: Please vote for a restart on each describe: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1785

Comment: Worth mentioning: If using not using angular with protractor, you will have to move `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` into the  beforeEach. IE    `beforeEach(function() { browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; });`

Answer (score 4):

In protractor.conf.js:

```
capabilities:{
    'shardTestFiles': true,
    'maxInstances': 1
}
```

This will open and close the browser with each .spec file, but you may lose some of the reporting capabilities from standard plugins. If shardTestFiles is false, it will open the browser, run onPrepare, run all tests serially, then close the browser.