# Protractor : Refreshing browser instance between testsuites

Tags: protractor

I am running multiple test suits in series and hence the same `browser` object of protractor is getting used in all test suites. Is there a way in protractor to flush the state of this `browser` object after each test suite is finished i.e. making the `browser` object stateless across the testsuites.

Comment: Having 'refresh' or 'relaunch' browser in teardown/setup?

Comment: Basically after each test suite I am closing all the windows and then when a new testsuite is initiated it is not able to find elements because browser is closed. What I am expecting is : instead of taking browser as in closed state, the new state should start its own browser instance. Hope that makes some sense.

Comment: browser.quit() in teardown and new Browser(host + page); in setup!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991395/how-to-so-to-speak-restart-or-close-browser-after-every-protractor-spec-test should probably solve your query

Comment: @SakshiSingla yeah, this looks like a duplicate. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this capability can help: restartBrowserBetweenTests

Example:

```
 capabilities: {
'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
'args': ['profile.default_content_settings.popups:1'] }
},

restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,

plugins: [{
package: 'protractor-console',
logLevels: ['info']
}],

baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'

}
```