# Open each spec in a new window - Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have few specs like :

```
specs: ['spec1.js','spec2.js','spec3.js],
```

I think all these specs run one by one in the same window that was opened.

How can I do like :

Open a new window > Run a spec > Close the window > Open a new Window > Run the next spec > Close the window .... and so on ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use new feature of protractor in your config file:

```
restartBrowserBetweenTests: true
```

you can find detailed discussions on this feature here : [How to, so to speak, restart or close browser after every protractor -spec test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991395/how-to-so-to-speak-restart-or-close-browser-after-every-protractor-spec-test)

Comment: this restarts between each `it` block, not each spec.  Makes your tests extremely slow, and also won't work if your spec needs to run any `beforeAll` functionality (very likely) as this only runs once before the entire suite

Comment: Thank you Ram. Giving only this in my config.js worked for me .    }, 
 capabilities: {
browserName: 'chrome',
chromeOptions: {
args: [ "--start-maximized" ]
   }
 },
 //set to true So each spec will be executed in own browser instance. default value is false
 restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to add to capabilities this options:

```
shardTestFiles: true
maxInstances: 1
```

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L158

So each spec will be executed in own browser instance.

But you might get errors with reporting - since Jasmine will be re-initialized between each spec file. I solved this with producing separate junit XML and combining them together after execution.

Comment: Hi @Xotabu4, I tried this and it worked. But as you told, the generated report has only the details of the first test case. How can I get details of all tests in the report?

Comment: It is a long answer - ping me in skype or somewhere, or create new question and mention me.