# In protractor can I define the browser specially to the spec because I want to run 2 specs in 2 different browsers

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have 2 specs which need to be run in none parallel mode and 1 spec should run in chrome and other is in firefox .

This is my config.js

```
   exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
//Potractor will run tests in parallel against each set of capabilities. 
//Please note that if multiCapabilities is defined, the runner will ignore the capabilities configuration   

    multiCapabilities: [{
        'name': 'test1',
        browserName: 'firefox',
        'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            args: ['--verbose'],
            binary: 'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe',
            specs: ['src/com/sam/scriptjs/iframes.spec.js']
        },
        }, {
            'name': 'test2',
          browserName: 'chrome',
          specs: ['src/com/sam/scriptjs/rightclickme.spec.js']
        }],
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'

}
```

This is my chrometest.spec.js
describe('chrome desc', function() {

```
  it('Navigae to the site using chrome', function() {         
        browser.driver.get(browser.baseUrl);
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');

  });
  });
```

This is my firefoxtest.spec.js. Kindly let me know if there is a way and I already checked the similar [How to, so to speak, restart or close browser after every protractor -spec test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991395/how-to-so-to-speak-restart-or-close-browser-after-every-protractor-spec-test?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it's insufficient to solve my query . Thank you .

```
describe('firefox desc', function() {
      it('Navigae to the site using firefox', function() {        
            browser.driver.get(browser.baseUrl);
            expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');

      });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be achieved with multicapabilities instead of capabilities. Can you try with below snippet.

```
multiCapabilities: [{
    'name': 'test1',
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    specs: ['chrometest.spec.js']
  }, {
    'name': 'test2',
    'browserName': 'firefox',
    specs: ['firefoxtest.spec.js']
  }],
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you dheeraj for your suggestion , I modified my config,js , please see in the question I edited it . However , now it throws  new Error('Spec patterns did not match any files.');

Comment: Looks like some issue with spec file paths, can you try something like ['./src/com/sam/scriptjs/rightclickme.spec.js']. Also there is looks it should be 'rightclickme.spec.js' instead there is comma, might be typo.

Comment: Thank you I corrected the typo my bad . Now it throws crossbrowerconfig.js:15
  specs: ['src/com/sam/scriptjs/nonangularstackscript.js']
  ^^^^^

Comment: Can you brief the exact error in the console. I didn't get the issue

Comment: Hi dheeraj Thank you for your support , I managed to solve it by adding few lines . Now the errors are gone ,  Also I had to remove name': 'test1', since it throwed an error .Thanks again and have a nice day .

Comment: Cool! Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

After went though dhreeraj's answer and some further reading and  , below config.js is worked for me  in Version 5.4.2 of protractor and Jasmine .

```
    exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  directConnect: false,


  multiCapabilities: [{
      browserName: 'firefox',
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            args: ['--verbose'],
            binary: 'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'
       //Need to start cmd via admin mode to avoid permission error
        },
      specs: ['src/com/sam/scriptjs/draganddrop.spec.js']
    }, 
    {
        browserName : 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [ "--start-maximized" ]
                     },
        specs: ['src/com/sam/scriptjs/iframes.spec.js']

    }],
    maxSessions: 1,//To run in sequential mode so first Firefox then chrome 
    //without max session it will open two windows at the same time for both browsers
     seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'

}
```