# Getting issue( browser instance ) while running test suite in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

Programming language used is javascript (promises flow disabled) : using async await to disable the asynchronous nature of javascript

My every test case in test suite has structure like above. Now, How can i want every test case belonging to test suite to be run in a sequence following the trend like

1. Opening of browser instance for a first test case & running the whole test case which is happening
2. then closing the above instance of first test case irrespective of the failure/success run.
3. Now opening the new browser instance for 2nd test case-->>running whole test case--->>closing the browser instance of this particular test case--->>
4. Now opening the new browser instance for 3rd test case-->>running whole test case--->>closing the browser instance of this particular test case--->>

Is this advisable to run the test suite in this way? If yes, then how should i manage with the commands like browser.close() or whatever your approach is. I have tried this but getting such errors like

> AfterAll Failed: invalid session id

Every test case structure

```
describe("Login Suite", () => {
    beforeEach(async function () {

    //browser instance initialization & application navigation is happening here

    })

    it('Test case name', async function () {
        try {

        // Include test steps       

        } catch (e) {
            browser.logger.info("Test SWM-2019065 failed with exception: " + e)
            expect(true).toBe(false, e)
        }
    })

    afterEach(async function () {
        //await browser.restart();
    or
    //await browser.close();

    })
})
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to close and reopen the browser after each test. If so, good news! There is a configuration option for that: [How to, so to speak, restart or close browser after every protractor -spec test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991395/how-to-so-to-speak-restart-or-close-browser-after-every-protractor-spec-test)

Comment: Thanks @SpinyNorman for helping me out, your referencing to the solution is much appreciated. My major problem has been solved but only facing a little issue, by implementing the above solution, when i run some particular test case by putting in focus ( fdescribe -->this runs a particular test case belonging to a suite ), it doesnt run that particular test case, it starts running whole suite.